# Tools can be used for converting TSQL Server 2005 stored procedures to understandable flowchart or similar things?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have to read a lot of stored procedures and they are mess! So I wonder that is there any free tool that can convert stored procedures to some things that can be more understandable? (Flow chart, diagram...)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools for this purpose.
[Code Visual to Flow chart](http://www.fatesoft.com/s2f/index.htm), it can take code in various languages and can show flow chart.
Hope, it'll be helpful.